# Crash on UITableView willDisplayCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

I am getting an intermittent crash on a specific line in my app.  I can't recreate the issue. In all my testing using two different iPad, and all the emulators I can't get it to crash, but I've had 36 user crashes caused by this in the last month. 
Below is the relevant code and the crash report for CrashLytics.

The line always shown as crashing is;

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Purchase Full Version Now (%@)",nil), self.sellPrice];
```

Hope someone can help, and I appreciate any advice.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *titleCellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Default Type",nil);
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Default Attendee",nil);
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PDF Set-up",nil);
                break;
            case 3:
                titleCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Topic and Item Numbering",nil);
                titleCellLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightBold];
                titleCellLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                [titleCellLabel sizeToFit];
                titleCellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 12, titleCellLabel.frame.size.width, titleCellLabel.frame.size.height);
                [[cell contentView] addSubview:titleCellLabel];
                break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1){
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Version",nil);
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Feedback",nil);
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Help",nil);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2){
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
               cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Backup Data to Email",nil);
               break;
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Restore Previous Full Version Purchase",nil);
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Purchase Full Version Now (%@)",nil), self.sellPrice];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the crash report;

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by Paul at Tue, 06 Feb 2018 01:22:20 GMT
# Platform: ios
# OS Version: 10.3.3 (14G60)
# Device: iPad 4
# RAM Free: 7.1%
# Disk Free: 13.2%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeb1f4c fixupMethodList(method_list_t*, bool, bool) + 103
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aea4d01 NXMapInsert + 62
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeb19e9 prepareMethodLists(objc_class*, method_list_t**, int, bool, bool) + 88
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeab2d3 realizeClass(objc_class*) + 918
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeaebc7 lookUpImpOrForward + 94
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeaeb65 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 26
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeb51af _objc_msgSend_uncached + 14
7  Simple Meeting Minutes         0x96697 -[MMSettingsTableVC tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] (MMSettingsTableVC.m:195)
8  UIKit                          0x21179ca9 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 814
9  UIKit                          0x21179de5 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 66
10 UIKit                          0x21167d79 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2190
11 UIKit                          0x2117e8db -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
12 UIKit                          0x20f2af0f -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 178
13 UIKit                          0x20e49483 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1224
14 QuartzCore                     0x1eaa1cb7 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 126
15 QuartzCore                     0x1ea95d77 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 354
16 QuartzCore                     0x1ea95c05 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
17 QuartzCore                     0x1ea24839 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 320
18 QuartzCore                     0x1ea42fdb CA::Transaction::commit() + 578
19 UIKit                          0x20e3f93b _afterCACommitHandler + 238
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1bbdb803 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1bbd9a55 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1bbda017 __CFRunLoopRun + 1358
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
25 GraphicsServices               0x1d2d7b41 GSEventRunModal + 80
26 UIKit                          0x20eafa53 UIApplicationMain + 150
27 App Name                       0x63123 main (main.m:16)
28 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b31a4eb start + 2

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeb1f4c fixupMethodList(method_list_t*, bool, bool) + 103
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aea4d01 NXMapInsert + 62
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeb19e9 prepareMethodLists(objc_class*, method_list_t**, int, bool, bool) + 88
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeab2d3 realizeClass(objc_class*) + 918
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeaebc7 lookUpImpOrForward + 94
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeaeb65 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 26
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1aeb51af _objc_msgSend_uncached + 14
7  App Name                       0x96697 -[MMSettingsTableVC tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] (MMSettingsTableVC.m:195)
8  UIKit                          0x21179ca9 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 814
9  UIKit                          0x21179de5 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 66
10 UIKit                          0x21167d79 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2190
11 UIKit                          0x2117e8db -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
12 UIKit                          0x20f2af0f -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 178
13 UIKit                          0x20e49483 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1224
14 QuartzCore                     0x1eaa1cb7 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 126
15 QuartzCore                     0x1ea95d77 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 354
16 QuartzCore                     0x1ea95c05 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
17 QuartzCore                     0x1ea24839 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 320
18 QuartzCore                     0x1ea42fdb CA::Transaction::commit() + 578
19 UIKit                          0x20e3f93b _afterCACommitHandler + 238
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1bbdb803 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1bbd9a55 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1bbda017 __CFRunLoopRun + 1358
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
25 GraphicsServices               0x1d2d7b41 GSEventRunModal + 80
26 UIKit                          0x20eafa53 UIApplicationMain + 150
27 App Name                       0x63123 main (main.m:16)
28 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b31a4eb start + 2

#1. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3ee73c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a2745 _pthread_wqthread + 728
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a245c start_wqthread + 8

#2. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3d8900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3d86e1 mach_msg + 44
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1bbdbbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1bbda065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6  Foundation                     0x1c481af5 <redacted> + 258
7  Foundation                     0x1c49e76d <redacted> + 86
8  UIKit                          0x217b0ad9 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 128
9  Foundation                     0x1c5658eb <redacted> + 1122
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a493b _pthread_body + 216
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a485d _pthread_start + 234
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a2468 thread_start + 8

#3. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  App Name                       0xbb343 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1057603
1  App Name                       0xbb343 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1057603
2  App Name                       0xbb23b CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1057339
3  App Name                       0xaf18d CLSHandler + 1008013
4  App Name                       0xaaed7 CLSMachExceptionServer + 990935
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a493b _pthread_body + 216
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a485d _pthread_start + 234
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a2468 thread_start + 8

#4. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3d8900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3d86e1 mach_msg + 44
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1bbdbbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1bbda065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6  CFNetwork                      0x1c20a393 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 402
7  Foundation                     0x1c5658eb <redacted> + 1122
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a493b _pthread_body + 216
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a485d _pthread_start + 234
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a2468 thread_start + 8

#5. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3ed808 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a3c43 _pthread_cond_wait + 560
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a4fc5 pthread_cond_wait + 38
3  libc++.1.dylib                 0x1ae3fc57 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 118
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x1fa94261 <redacted> + 88
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x1fa941e5 <redacted> + 154
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x1fa940ed <redacted> + 18
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x1fa9432f <redacted> + 66
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a493b _pthread_body + 216
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a485d _pthread_start + 234
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a2468 thread_start + 8

#6. WebThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3d8900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3d86e1 mach_msg + 44
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1bbdbbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1bbda065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1bb2cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6  WebCore                        0x1fd4bce3 <redacted> + 426
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a493b _pthread_body + 216
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a485d _pthread_start + 234
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a2468 thread_start + 8

#7. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3ee73c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a28eb _pthread_wqthread + 1150
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a245c start_wqthread + 8

#8. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b3ee73c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a28eb _pthread_wqthread + 1150
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4a245c start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: First, why are you modifying UI in `willDisplayCell`??? Why can't you configure the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which is what it's for.. Secondly, every time `willDisplayCell` gets called, you are adding a NEW label to the cell's contentView.. cells are recycled so if I scrolled your table 100 times, that 4th cell in section 0 would have 100 labels. Finally, what type is `self.sellPrice`??? Are you sure it's a string?

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for your comment.  I'm using willDisplayCell as I need to add a subview label to one of the cells.  As it's a static table I considered it best to this rather than cellForRowAtIndexPath.  self.sellPrice is definitely a string.  Great point about adding the new label overtime the table is scrolled. <br/> What I have done is to not use willDisplayCell and instead created IBOutlet in the Storybook for each cell and set the cell test labels from viewDidLoad.  That seems to work fine and will hopefully be more stable.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting that cells are reused? You may end up with this added subview in every cell!

Comment: @Brandon `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is meant to finish as fast as possible if you want really smooth scrolling.  `willDisplayCell` is the best place to populate cells, but that is not adding a views. Have a look at this : https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5 Look at the first highlight.

Comment: @Stoyan; https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/proper-use-of-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willdisplaycell/
I've never seen code configure a cell in `willDisplay` instead of `cellForRow`

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Shashank; Wow, that was 2 years ago, thanks for your interest.  As I said below, I took on the advice and stopped using willDisplayCell, linked to each of the static cells using IBOutlet and handled the whole thing in viewDidLoad.  These days I tend to avoid using static tables and only use dynamic, seems to be much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon indicated, using willDisplayCell and adding a new cell content Label every scroll is likely to be the issue.  I was using willDisplayCell as I needed to add a subview label to one of the cells.
 So rather than use willDisplayCell I have instead created IBOutlet in the Storybook for each cell, set the cell text labels and load the cell subview from within viewDidLoad. That seems to work fine and should be more stable.
 Thanks for your assistance Brandon, just needed someone to point out the obvious.